# Show bivariate normal distribution with non-diagonal covariance belongs to curved exponential family?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, exponential-family

**Question:**

Suppose that $(X_{i}, Y_{i})$, $i = 1, \dots ,n$ are sampled i.i.d. from the two-dimensional normal distribution

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X & Y
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\mathcal{N}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \theta\\
\theta & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right),
$$

with $\theta \in \Omega = (-1, 1)$. Show that the joint density of $(X_{i}, Y_{i})$, $i = 1, \dots ,n$ is a 2-dimensional curved exponential family.

**Attempt:**

Since the density $f_{X, Y}$ can be expressed as

$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1 - \theta^{2}}}\exp\bigg\{-\frac{1}{2(1 - \theta^{2})}(x^{2} + y^{2}) + \frac{\theta}{1 - \theta^{2}}xy\bigg\},$$

the joint density is

$$\prod_{i = 1}^{n}f_{X_{i}, Y_{i}}(x_{i}, y_{i}) = 
\left(\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1 - \theta^{2}}}\right)^{n}\exp\bigg\{-\frac{1}{2(1 - \theta^{2})}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_{i}^{2} + y_{i}^{2}) + \frac{\theta}{1 - \theta^{2}}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i}\bigg\}$$

from which the natural parameter $\eta(\theta)$ is

$$\eta(\theta) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2(1 - \theta^{2})} & \frac{\theta}{1 - \theta^{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How to show the exponential family is curved? According to my understanding, we need to show $\eta_{2}$ is a non-linear function of $\eta_{1}$, although it is not obvious to me how.

Comment: $\eta_2$ is a differentiable function of $\eta_1.$ If it is linear, then its derivative must be constant.  Is the derivative constant?